# Can I use getter to retroactively apply values in js?

Tags: javascript

I have an object `player` with the following:

```
var player = {
    moneyRatio: 3, //Multiplier of money as a function of number.
    globalMultiplier: 1.000 //Total multiplier, multiplies ALL production.
};
```

I have this particular upgrade called `benefits`, which is supposed to reduce `player.moneyRatio` by 0.002 per building `gradStudent` you have.

```
{
    name: "Benefits",
    desc: "Your graduate students seem more professional, giving them a bonus to money scaling.",
    moneyCost: 200,
    scienceCost: null,
    popularityCost: null,
    requirement: () => RESOURCES[0].count >= 10,
    result : function() {
        player.moneyRatio = /* ??? */
    },
    id: 'benefitsUpg', //Id used to fetch stuff
    html: `<button id="benefitsUpgButton" class="upgradeButtons">Benefits</button>     
    <div class='tooltip' id='benefitsUpgTooltip'> 
        <span>Your graduate students seem more professional, giving them a bonus to money scaling.<br /> </span>
        <span class='tooltipMoneyColor'> <span class='boldedNumbers' id='benefitsUpgMoneyCostDisp'> </span><br /> dollars </span>
        <span>----------------------------------------------------------------</span>
            <div>Money Scaling Ratio: -0.002 per grad student </div>

    </div>`,
    index: 1 //Index to determine what is deleted when you buy the upgrade. Based ONLY upon what order the table is sorted by.
 },
```

I want to retroactively apply this, so if the player buys `benefits` with 5 grad students, the game will automatically subtract 0.01 from the moneyRatio. I **also** want to make sure that the -0.002 will also apply every time a NEW gradStudent is bought.

Is there a way to do this only within each upgrade? Preferrably I would like the `result` function to change `moneyRatio` so that it will automatically update. I don't want to have to make special functions and if/else statements for each upgrade like this (and I plan to have over 400 of these so it would become very cumbersome for me to add if/else blocks for every special case.

I tried using the `get` "function" (?) but I don't really know if I can use it to this purpose, and if I can, I don't really know how to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more context. For example, what does this mean: "so if the player buys benefits with 5 grad students" and "every time a NEW gradStudent is bough". What does buying benefits with 5 grad students mean and what does it mean by buy a grad student?

Comment: @Aaronius `benefits` is the upgrade. This upgrade decreases the `player.moneyRatio` by 0.002 each. `gradStudent` is an object that can be bought or purchased (code for that isn't really important to this). If you DO NOT have this upgrade, then the 0.002 reduction doesn't apply. However, **once you buy the upgrade,** I want `player.moneyRatio` to retroactively add this reduction. For example, if you own 5 `gradStudent` objects before buying, your `moneyRatio` would be 3, but once you bought `benefits`, it would be 2.99, and each successive `gradStudent` would subtract another 0.002.